# Magento shipping quotes not working after upgrade from 1.5.0.1 to 1.6

Tags: magento

just wondering if anyone else has encountered this. Upgraded and everything went well except that in the checkout process we get the "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time" error, making it impossible to check out.
Anyone know what might have caused this, and if there's a fix?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change the country to which you are shipping and billing. I had the same problem and when I changed it to the correct country, I got it working.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with FREE SHIPPING. Issue : Under Admin > Config > Shipping Methods > FREE SHIPPing

Minimum Order Amount was set to $100. I set the minimum order amount to $1 and it worked fine. Maybe this might help. goodluck